# Get/Calculate zoom level from lat/long delta

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

is there any way to get Google Maps zoom level calculate from lat/long delta values from the Google Maps SDK for iOS?

or maybe calculate it via Objective C ?

thanks

Comment: I guess you are trying to change the zoom, so both points fit in the map?
In this case you can use 
+ (GMSCameraUpdate *) fitBounds:(GMSCoordinateBounds *) bounds; 
or
 + (GMSCameraUpdate *) fitBounds:(GMSCoordinateBounds *) bounds withPadding:(CGFloat)padding ;

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get a calculated zoom, to take lat/long delta value, and then convert to a zoom level. did not really understand your suggestion, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

From GMSCoordinateBounds.h:

```
 /**
 * Inits the northEast and southWest bounds corresponding
 * to the rectangular region defined by the two corners.
 *
 * It is ambiguous whether the longitude of the box
 * extends from |coord1| to |coord2| or vice-versa;
 * the box is constructed as the smaller of the two variants, eliminating the
 * ambiguity.
 */
 - (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord1
          coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord2;
```

It can be used to set the camera to fit the bounds with the appropriate zoom level.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-45.43563456, -23.32543646);
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-21.32145323, -12.32455435);
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord1 coordinate:coord2];

[mapView moveCamera: [GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds]];
```

Comment: If i have 3-4 coordinates, than how can I find northEast and southWest. I did try includingCoordinate and includingPath. But it results a different

Answer (score 0):

if somebody is searching it for swift, i also needed it for autocompletion, you can set bounds (example for south west germany near freiburg and stuttgart):

```
let coord1 : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.10009, 8.206787);
        let coord2 :  CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.10009, 8.206787);
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: (coord1), coordinate: (coord2))
        placesClient?.autocompleteQuery(autoQuery, bounds: bounds, filter: filter, callback: { (results, error: NSError?) -> Void in and so on.......
```